# Change Field labels in VF page

Tags: apex, customlabel, label, detail-page, detail

I have below VF page that is look alike of standrad detail page. Now I need to change field labels in the vf page. Can someone suggest a wayout please?

**Code:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account_Plan_vod__c" standardStylesheets="true">  
    <apex:pageBlock title="Kol Plan"/>

    <apex:dataTable value="{!Account_Plan_vod__c}"
                var="AP"
                cellPadding="4" border="1"> 

    <apex:column value="{!AP.Name}"/>
    </apex:dataTable>
    <apex:detail subject="{!Account_Plan_vod__c.Id}"  relatedList="true" title="false">


    </apex:detail>


      </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change button label at Object level then for Standard Object go  to

> Customize> Tab Names and Labels > Rename Tabs and Labels > Select
>   Object > edit > Change the name

For custom Object you can directly change the name.

Comment: I need to change Custom Field labels only in this VF Page.

Comment: then you need to create custom page using apex:inputField and then you can change the label

Comment: Can I not change those field labels here in apex: detail somehow? Is it impossible?

Comment: You need to apply Javascript hacks

Comment: Can you please help me here?

Comment: you need to find their class name or Id And using Javascript Will change their text `document.getElementsByClassName('labelCol')[0].innerText ='test label';` but it is not recommend approach and i suggest you to go with apex:outputField approach. It will take less time and futureProof

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29969/discussion-between-sfdc-learner-and-tushar-sharma).